# How to read a number inside an attribute type

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Can someone tell Me how can I read the number 20.0 in this XML? I am using c# and XElements in XML.LinQ .

```
<attribute id="Width" unit="mm" type="float">20.0</attribute>
```

so this attribute is a sub element and when i write

```
gear.Attributes[0].Type.Value;
```

I get "float"

and I defined "Type" like this

```
Type = el.Attribute("type").ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should've stored the `XElement.Value` into your model somehow, just like you did for `Type`. Something like this :

```
yourModelInstance.Type = (string)el.Attribute("type");
yourModelInstance.Value = (float)el;
```

Comment: This Actually Worked. but The value I get is Zero!

Comment: @Afshinzkh create a [minimal but complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code sample to reproduce the problem, post it in a new question. Example of MCVE (but this one doesn't show the problem in your comment) : https://dotnetfiddle.net/4dmEZx

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the type of the value, not the value itself.

You can actually just cast the XElement to the type of the value you are expecting:

```
    var result = (float)gear.Attributes[0];
```

You can read more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx

Comment: this does not work. this gives me the class value. and I have an error that says: "Cannot Convert Type "Model.Moment" to float". Model.Moment is my class name

Comment: `gear` is of type Model.Moment?

Comment: Seems like `gear` is instance of another user-defined class which has property/field `Attributes` which is a collection of `Model.Moment`. That's why `gear.Attributes[0]` yeilds a `Model.Moment` instance, according to the error message.

Comment: it is exatly defined as har07 said.